# uwp get notification for visual state changed in Custom Media Controls

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, visualstatemanager, visualstates

in my uwp app I have **Custom Media Transport Controls** and I want to get notified whenever my controls appear and disappear from screen so I can match the cursor appear and disappear with it as well.

> this is what I have tried so far :

From **generic.xaml** in my style of controls I found following **VisualStateGroup** which controls the fadein and fadeout of controls.

```
<VisualStateGroup x:Name="ControlPanelVisibilityStates">
    <VisualState x:Name="ControlPanelFadeIn">
        <Storyboard>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="ControlPanel_ControlPanelVisibilityStates_Border">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0" />
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="1" />
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Y" Storyboard.TargetName="TranslateVertical" From="50" To="0.5" Duration="0:0:0.3" />
        </Storyboard>
    </VisualState>
    <VisualState x:Name="ControlPanelFadeOut">
        <Storyboard>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="ControlPanel_ControlPanelVisibilityStates_Border">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1" />
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.7" Value="0" />
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsHitTestVisible" Storyboard.TargetName="ControlPanel_ControlPanelVisibilityStates_Border">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="False" />
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Y" Storyboard.TargetName="TranslateVertical" From="0.5" To="50" Duration="0:0:0.7" />
        </Storyboard>
    </VisualState>
</VisualStateGroup>
```

So I thought I should get this group in my **OnApplyTemplate** method and then assign the state changed event to it.

```
protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
{
    //other irrelivent code
    ControlsFade = (VisualStateGroup)GetTemplateChild("ControlPanelVisibilityStates");
        ControlsFade.CurrentStateChanged += 
    ControlsFade_CurrentStateChanged;
    base.OnApplyTemplate();
}

public class ControlFadeChangedEventArgs
{
    public bool Appeared { get; set; }
}
public event EventHandler<ControlFadeChangedEventArgs> ControlFadeChanged;

private void ControlsFade_CurrentStateChanged(object sender, VisualStateChangedEventArgs e)
{
    bool fadein = false;
    if (e.NewState.Name == "ControlPanelFadeIn")
            fadein = true;

    ControlFadeChanged?.Invoke(this, new ControlFadeChangedEventArgs { Appeared = fadein });
}
```

> I wired it all up and further logic is being done on the page, which is irrelevant in this case. I debugged with a break point and found out that **ControlsFade_CurrentStateChanged** is never firing.

Comment: Is it possible that ControlsFade is null? To understand what happened we may need a full sample.

Comment: Where are you changing the active `VisualState`?

Comment: I have posted the answer please have a look @MartinZikmund

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within my custom controls I was unsubscribing to all the events related to my custom media controls in the **UnLoaded** event of the media controls( including the ControlsFade_CurrentStateChanged) and as it turns out whenever controls go fullscreen, the **Unloaded** event is triggered so it removed the subscription to this event and hence it was not firing after that. so I commented out the unloaded event and now it is working as expected.

> Unsubscription of events is important to prevent memory leaks, please let me know in the comments how I can unsubscribe without causing this issue.

Comment: Can you attach them in Loaded again?

Comment: yeah I will try to do that